# What is the best way to compare two yocto kernels?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, petalinux

I am using petalinux from Xilinx which builds around yocto.

I have one yocto that works fine, but is for the wrong Embedded Hardware (wrong board), and another which does not work but is for the correct board.

Therefore I would like to compare the settings in the two. The simplest but slowest way would be to iterative other Settings in the GUI, but it just seems tedious. So I am wondering if there is any way to somehow compare them by line or the config files etc.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can look into each kernel recipe's `WORKDIR` and compare the `.config` files. This is **exactly** what is set up for the kernel to build. To make it easier to compare, running `bitbake -c savedefconfig <kernel recipe>` and then comparing the `defconfig` in `WORKDIR` could highlight missing "top" drivers/configurations by omitting to show their dependencies.

Comment: Config files you can also get by reading /proc/config.gz

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov, it depends to the configuration option and often on embedded systems it's disabled by obvious reasons.